# Bitbucket fatal: Can't access remote

Tags: ftp, bitbucket, sftp

I tried to set up sftp connection between Bitbucket and Runcloud server. Runcloud only uses sftp connection. Bitbucket config:

```
image: php:7.3

pipelines:
 branches:
   master:
     - step:
         name: Deploy to production
         deployment: production
         script:
           - apt-get update
           - apt-get -qq install git-ftp
           - git ftp init --user $SFTP_username --passwd $FTP_password sftp://runcloud@1.111.111.11/home/runcloud/webapps/mywebsite/wp-content/themes/mywebsiteTheme
```

Connection always fails with error **fatal: Can't access remote 'sftp://1.111.111.11', exiting...**

I tried a different sftp Path combination but the result always the same.
sftp://1.111.111.11/home/runcloud/webapps/mywebsite/wp-content/themes/mywebsiteTheme
sftp://mywebsite/home/runcloud/webapps/mywebsite/wp-content/themes/mywebsiteTheme

My website
Root Path: /home/runcloud/webapps/mywebsite
Public Path: /home/runcloud/webapps/mywebsite

Runcload have different as "normal" set up for ftp. For example to conect with FileZila HOST is my server ip. And to get to my website i have to navigate /webapps/mywebsite
[image]

Not sure what I doing wrong is my sftp path incorrect?

Comment: Is port 22 open on that IP? Is Bitbucket Pipelines permitted to use it?

Comment: Yes, port 22 open. Yes I can use Pipelines.

Comment: I saw that you could already use Pipelines, but are Pipelines IPs permitted to connect to 1.111.111.11:22? That IP doesn't permit connections from my IP here, so there may be a firewall issue.

Comment: Long story short. Runcloud have build in option for bitbucket. "Custom" Pipelines not working in Runcloud  according support.